# Pandas create new row for every match of a string in a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets (data-frames), one of them contains text and the other contains words that I am searching and I would like to know if they are contained in some of those texts and tag them.

The way I would like to do it is by adding a new row in the data-frame 2 for every word that matches a value contained in the data-frame 1,

An example of it:

data-frame 1

```
word        id
'sushi'     1
'pizza'     2
'burger'    3
'plaza'     4
'park'      5
'mountain'  6
```

data-frame 2 to search in:

NOTE: data-frame 2 has more columns but they are not relevant to solve the problem

```
text
'I eat pizza in the park'  
'I eat sushi' 
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'
'He eats'
```

The desired output is the following

```
text                                      contained_word_id
'I eat pizza in the park'                 2
'I eat pizza in the park'                 5
'I eat sushi'                             1
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  1
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  2
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  4
'He eats'                                 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `findall` then `explode` and `map`

```
df2['word'] = df2.text.str.findall('|'.join(df1.word.tolist()))
df2 = df2.explode('word')
df2['id'] = df2.word.map(df1.set_index('word')['id'])
df2
Out[443]: 
                                       text   word   id
0               'I eat pizza in the park'    pizza  2.0
0               'I eat pizza in the park'     park  5.0
1                            'I eat sushi'   sushi  1.0
2  'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  sushi  1.0
2  'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  pizza  2.0
2  'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  plaza  4.0
3                                 'He eats'    NaN  NaN
```